# Pandas to_sql change column type from varchar to text

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I wrote a little script to copy a table between SQL servers.
It works, but one of the columns changed type from varchar to text...
How do I make it to copy a table with the same columns types?

```
import pymssql
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


db_server= 1.2.3.4\\r2
db_database="Test_DB"
db_user="vaf"
db_password="1234"

local_db_server="1.1.1.1\\r2"
local_db_database="Test_DB"
local_db_user="vaf"
local_db_password="1234"

some_query=("""
select * from some_table
""")




def main():
    conn=pymssql.connect(server=local_db_server,user=local_db_user,password=local_db_password,database=local_db_database,charset='UTF-8')
    data=pd.io.sql.read_sql(some_query,conn)

    connection_string='mssql+pymssql://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(db_user,db_password,db_server,db_database)
    engine=create_engine(connection_string)
    data.to_sql(name="some_table",con=engine,if_exists='replace',index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Consider three approaches:

**SPECIFY TYPES** *(proactive as it anticipates ahead)*

Using the *dtype* argument of [`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), pass a dictionary of [sqlalchemy types](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#generic-types) for named columns.

```
data.to_sql(name="some_table", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False,
            dtype={'datefld': sqlalchemy.DateTime(), 
                   'intfld':  sqlalchemy.types.INTEGER(),
                   'strfld': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR(length=255),
                   'floatfld': sqlalchemy.types.Float(precision=3, asdecimal=True),
                   'booleanfld': sqlalchemy.types.Boolean}
```

**DELETE DATA** *(proactive as it anticipates ahead)*

Clean out table with `DELETE` action query. Then, migrate only the data from pandas to SQL Server without structurally changing table since `to_sql` *replace* argument re-creates the table. This approach assumes dataframe is always consistent (no new columns / changed types) with database table.

```
def main():
   connection_string = 'mssql+pymssql://{}:{}@{}/{}'\
                         .format(db_user,db_password,db_server,db_database)
   engine = create_engine(connection_string)

   # IMPORT DATA INTO DATA FRAME
   data = pd.read_sql(some_query, engine)

   # SQL DELETE (CLEAN OUT TABLE) VIA TRANSACTION
   with engine.begin() as conn:     
      conn.execute("DELETE FROM some_table")

   # MIGRATE DATA INTO DATA FRAME (APPEND NOT REPLACE)
   data.to_sql(name='some_table', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

**MODIFY COLUMN** *(reactive as it fixes ad-hoc)*

Alter the column after migration with a DDL SQL statement.

```
def main():
   connection_string = 'mssql+pymssql://{}:{}@{}/{}'\
                         .format(db_user,db_password,db_server,db_database)
   engine = create_engine(connection_string)

   # IMPORT DATA INTO DATA FRAME
   data = pd.read_sql(some_query, engine)

   # MIGRATE DATA INTO DATA FRAME 
   data.to_sql(name="some_table", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

   # ALTER COLUMN TYPE (ASSUMING USER HAS RIGHTS/PRIVILEGES)
   with engine.begin() as conn:     
      conn.execute("ALTER TABLE some_table ALTER COLUMN mytextcolumn VARCHAR(255);")
```

*I recommend the second approach as I believe databases should be agnostic to application code like python and pandas. Hence, initial build/re-build of table schema should be a planned, manual process, and no script should structurally change a database on the fly, only interact with data.*