# Data truncation when using pandas to_sql into VARCHAR(MAX) SQL column

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

**Problem:**

When importing dataframe to SQL table, getting a truncation error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22001', '[22001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated. (8152) (SQLExecDirectW); [22001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)')
```

The column in question is *ProjectDescription* (see column list below). I've quoted the line that produces the error. I'm not entirely sure this is the source of the issue, but I think the column was originally created as VARCHAR(300). The value causing trouble is 307 characters long; 9 truncated as below. That leaves 298. Original size limit 300, 2 for 's, that leaves 298 I guess? Not sure but it's a strange length to be truncating to.

**Code causing the issue:**

```
dataframe.to_sql('tblImport', eng, schema='dbo', if_exists='append', index=False, dtype=dict_SQL_dtypes)
```

**Attempted solutions:**

- Setting TEXTSIZE in SQL
- Changing column type to VARCHAR / NVARCHAR, changing length to 1000 or MAX
- Setting datatypes (dtype) to `sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR` (idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631181/pandas-to-sql-change-column-type-from-varchar-to-text))
- Before import, sorting dataframe by descending length of ProjectDescription column to put longest value in top row
- Dropping tables and recreating the column as VARCHAR(MAX) as the data type in case the original length of the column was somehow still limiting the import
- Altering column type through SQL query directly

**Versions:**

- OS: Windows 10
- python: 3.6
- pandas: 0.24.1
- sqlalchemy: 1.2.17
- pyodbc: 4.0.25
- DB management tool: MSSMS
- SQL server 12

*DB connection:*

```
pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}};SERVER={0};DATABASE={1};UID={2};PWD={3}".format(serv, db, usr, pwd))
```

*Engine:*

```
create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://{}@sqlserver:{}@{}:1433/{}?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server'.format(usr, pwd, serv, db), echo=True)
```

ProjectDescription column character_maximum_length from DB schema: -1

*Columns:*

```
Column Name          | Data Type      | Allow Nulls
ProjectUID           | varchar(60)    | Unchecked
Framework            | char(5)        | Checked
Partner              | char(3)        | Checked
SCUID                | char(9)        | Checked
ClientName           | varchar(255)   | Checked
PartnerProjectNumber | varchar(40)    | Checked
ProjectName          | varchar(255)   | Checked
ProjectDescription   | varchar(MAX)   | Checked
```

**Traceback:**

```
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1216, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 533, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
pyodbc.DataError: ('22001', '[22001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated. (8152) (SQLExecDirectW); [22001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_for_tests.py", line 258, in <module>
    outmsg = run()
  File "run_for_tests.py", line 252, in run
    process_result = process_data(file_type, file_name, relative_path, dict_clients)
  File "run_for_tests.py", line 204, in process_data
    update_sql_tables(df_base)
  File "server_interaction.py", line 74, in update_sql_tables
    dataframe.to_sql('tblImport', eng, schema='dbo', if_exists='append', index=False, dtype=dict_SQL_dtypes)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2532, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype, method=method)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 460, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype, method=method)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1174, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 686, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 599, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 980, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 273, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1099, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1240, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1458, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 296, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 276, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1216, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 533, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
  sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22001', '[22001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated. (8152) (SQLExecDirectW); [22001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)') [SQL: 'INSERT INTO dbo.[tblImport] ([ProjectUID], [Framework], [Partner], [SCUID], [ClientName], [PartnerProjectNumber], [ProjectName], [ProjectDescription]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (('xxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxx', 'xxxxxxx', 'ABC', 123, 'ABC', 'Provide competition facilities. Build this facility with a capacity of 9000 spectators  ... (9 characters truncated) ... m pool and diving facilities and athletes changing facilities to a competion standard and then, post games, convert it to a council operated facility'), ....)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/9h9h)
```

Comment: I am running on the same issue. Have you solved this issue somehow?

Comment: @debuggingXD Unfortunately nothing yet. I ended up nuking the database and rebuilding it with the column set to varchar (max) from the start