# Load DF to Redshift with Varchar(65535) in Python

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm currently working with Social Media data frame, X (Twitter), Facebook, Instagram, etc.

Some data had a long text, for example:

*" ValorFuturo  Santiago--Sep 12--Bupa Chile está potenciando la  operación de su laboratorio a través de la creación
de una nueva unidad de negocio denominada Bupa Lab, a  través de la cual...  Para acceder a la noticia completa, solicite su demo gratis AQUÍ"*

I'm using this function to load data from Python to Redshift:

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, URL

    def save_to_sql(df, table, schema, append=False):
        drivername = 'redshift+psycopg2'
        host       = 'host'
        port       = 5439
        username   = 'admin'
        password   = 'password'
        database   = 'dev'

        url_object = URL.create(
            drivername,
            username=username,
            password=password,
            host=host,
            port=port,
            database=database,
        )

        engine = create_engine(url_object)

        full_table_name = f'{schema}.{table}'

        return df.to_sql(full_table_name, engine, if_exists=('append' if append else 'replace'), index=False, method='multi', chunksize=10000)

save_to_sql(df, 'tablename', False)
```

The problem is, this function send data to redshift with varchar(256), i created manually a redshift table with varchar(65535), but the script change the type to varchar(256) for each columns. When the table find a long text the script fail because varchar(256) don't support the text size.

The error message is

***StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(256)***

How can i modify the function to force varchar(65535)?

I'm open to change the function and libraries, and only need send the data to redshift.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631181/pandas-to-sql-change-column-type-from-varchar-to-text) can help you ?
Like the solution, I would use the dtype argument to force the varchar of length 65535 for the column that need it.